# How to show that every non-trivial orbit of ODE is periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

I'm currently looking at the system of first order ODEs

$$
\begin{cases}
  x' = -y-x^2y \\
  y' = x+xy^2
\end{cases}
$$

and I try to show that every non-trivial orbit of the system is periodic. I'm lost how to approach this. I tried converting the system into polar coordinates (but this got ugly and the radius didn't stay constant). I know how to show that *no periodic orbits exists*  using Bendixson, but this is of no use here.

The system looks kind of symmetric, since the first line is equivalent to $-y(1-x^2)$ and the second line to $x(1+y^2)$, but I don't know where is could help me. I also looked the only fix point $(0, 0)$. It is non-hyperbolic (the Jacobian at $(0, 0)$ hat Eigenvalues $\lambda_{1/2} = \pm i$). Any hints on how to proceed are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

if you don't object to partial derivatives:  given system 
$$  \dot{x} = X(x,y) \; , \; $$
$$  \dot{y} = Y(x,y) \; , \; $$
the system is called Hamiltonian when
$$  \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} = 0.   $$

When this happens, we can solve an easy PDE system, finding (guessing) a function $H$ such that
$$ X = \frac{\partial H}{\partial y}  \; \; , \; \; \; Y = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} .   $$

We need
$$    \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = -x-xy^2 \; \; , \; \;   \frac{\partial H}{\partial y} = -y - x^2 y  $$
Just by inspection, we can take
$$  H = \frac{1}{2} \left( - x^2 - x^2 y^2 - y^2 \right) $$
This is constant on an orbit if and only if $$ x^2 y^2 + x^2 + y^2 $$
is constant, if and only if
$$ x^2 y^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 1 = \color{blue} {\left(x^2 + 1 \right)\left( y^2 + 1 \right)}$$ is constant. So, we agree with the first answer.

Here, $H$ is called the Hamiltonian function.
The orbits of the ODE lie within level curves of $H,$ as the chain rule says that $H$ stays constant on an orbit. When $H$ has a strict local minimum or strict local maximum at the equilibrium point, this means the orbits near the equilibrium  are little simple closed curves, ellipses or whatever.

This is pages 78-79 in the Third edition of Jordan and Smith, Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations.

Comment: +1 For this answer. Change the link Jagy because it leads to an actor page.

Answer (score 2):

This system admits a first integral:
$$
\frac{dx}{-y-x^2y}=\frac{dy}{x+xy^2}
$$
or
$$
\frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2}=-\frac{y\,dy}{1+y^2}
$$
gives us
$$\tag{1}
(1+x^2)(1+y^2)=C.
$$
The level sets defined by (1) are closed curves, except for the case $C=1$, which corresponds to the equilibrium point. Hence, all solutions are periodic.

Comment: What does _admit a first integral_ mean?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I could show that the orbits are bounded (in a _donut_). Then I could you Poincaré-Bendixson.

Comment: @user7802048 The first integral (or conserved quantity) is a function that is constant along an orbit.

Comment: The Poincaré–Bendixson theorem is about limit sets, not about solutions in general

Comment: The forumlation in our lecture states something along the lines: Let $y_0$ be a point in the phase space. If there forward-orbit is bounded and the limit set of $y_0$ doesn't contain an equilibrium the limit set is a periodic orbit. Doesn't this help here? If we could bound the forward-orbit it would mean that at least the limit set is a periodic orbit.

Comment: The periodic limit set does not mean the periodicity of the trajectories tending to it

Comment: +1 AVK nice answer

Comment: What does an general approach using this technique look like? I don't really understand what is going on here..

Comment: @user7802048 The approach used here is similar to that used in the analysis of the predator-prey system. This is a well-known system, often used as an example in lectures and books. Here are some links from the internet: http://math.bme.hu/~nagyi/diffeq/diffeq-09.pdf https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/210S19/Notes/Murray-Predator-Prey.pdf https://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/~ktch24/term1Notes(10).pdf